# Is there any way I could extend this to work with any value of currentLayer?

Tags: python, list, iteration, abstraction

For currentLayer = 1:

```
    for i1 in range(len(currentList)):
        currentList[i1] = someFunction(currentList[i1])
    return currentList
```

For currentLayer = 3:

```
    for i1 in range(len(currentList)):
        for i2 in range(len(currentList[i1])):
            for i3 in range(len(currentList[i1][i2])):
                currentList[i1][i2][i3] = someFunction(currentList[i1][i2][i3])
    return currentList
```

I'm not sure how to go about this or what question to even ask in order to figure this out.

Comment: Use a recursive function that checks whether the element is a list. If it is, it calls itself recursively on the element, otherwise it calls the function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation of what Barmar described.  It can handle lists nested to any depth.

For demonstration purposes, I've implemented `someFunction` as a function that returns the square of a number, and the list as a nested list of numeric types.  `applyFunction` is the recursive function that performs `someFunction` on every number in the list, replacing your nested `for` loops.

```
# A list of numbers, nested to differing levels
testList = [1, 2, [3, 4, 5], 6, [[7], [8, [9, 10, [11, 11.25]], 12], 13, 14], 15]

# A procedure to be applied to every primitive element in the list above
def someFunction(n):
    return n**2

# Apply someFunction to each number in the list, at any nesting depth
def applyFunction(currentList):
    for i in range(len(currentList)):
        if type(currentList[i]) in [int, float]:  # Apply function to relevant primitive types
            currentList[i] = someFunction(currentList[i])
        elif type(currentList[i]) == list:  # Enter nested lists and perform the above steps on them
            applyFunction(currentList[i])
    # After outer and all inner lists have been iterated over, return the result.
    # NOTE:  The returned result will be the same as the current state of the original input list.
    # This is because, since lists are mutable, we were modifying the original the whole time.
    return currentList

# Display the result, showing that every number in the list has been squared
result = applyFunction(testList)
print("Output of applyFunction is: " + str(result))
print("But the value of testList is now also " + str(testList))
```

There is an important caveat here:  As in the code in your original question, calling the function results both in returning a new list, AND in altering the original list.  If you *don't* want the original list to be altered, you would have to first create a deep copy and then call `applyFunction` on the deep copy.  Alternatively, you could rewrite `applyFunction` such that it builds a new list from the squared elements of the old list, instead of reassigning the elements of the old list to their squared values.